# Neo4j Graph depth traversal Cypher

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, traversal, depth

I'm using neo4j as a graph database and I want to return from a starting node neighbors of that node, and all the related neighbors to a depth varying from 1 to 3. I'm Doing this but it gets stuck:
Note that it is a large graph.

```
start n = node(*) where n.NID contains "9606.ENS3" 
MATCH (n)-[Rel1*1..3]-(m) RETURN m;
```

Anyone have a clue of  how to do traversals on a graph, and getting a result?

Comment: What Neo4j version are you using? What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm using 3.2.1 community

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows an old Cypher syntax. The [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/start/#query-start) says about the START clause:

> The START clause should only be used when accessing legacy indexes. In
>   all other cases, use MATCH instead (see Section 3.3.1, “MATCH”).

I believe this should work:

```
MATCH(n)-[Rel1*1..3]->(m)
WHERE n.NID contains "9606.ENS3"
RETURN m
```

Comment: Any clue to optimized as it is large dataset ? the browzer bugs

Comment: You can try specifying a known label in `n` and `m` nodes (something like `MATCH(n:NodeTypeA)-[Rel1*1..3]->(m:NodeTypeB)`). Creating an index in the n.NID property is a good idea too.

Comment: A  unique constraint is already created and adding the labels make it bug

Comment: What "bug" are you getting?

Comment: the browzer is blocked saying neio4j do not response

Comment: Well, this is not a bug. This probably is related with the size of your graph and the amount of memory that you have available... Take a look in the [memory tuning](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/#memory-tuning) section.

Comment: I already did , that's why I'm asking for a tric to optimize graph traversal on large sets

Comment: Hard to provide advice without more info. Can you EXPLAIN the query and paste the exported image (after all elements are expanded) of the query plan to your description?